# How can i resolve zsh: command not found: flutterfire in macOS?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I followed [document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#using-the-flutterfire-cli) to add firebase in my flutter app.
I got 1 warning and message like

```
    Warning: Pub installs executables into $HOME/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
    You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):
Warning: Pub installs executables into $HOME/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):

  export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Activated flutterfire_cli 0.1.1+2.
```

after this i used

```
flutterfire configure
```

and i got this error (not an error) `zsh: command not found: flutterfire`
How to resolve this ? and I this any environment error ?

Answer (score 104):

Set path for **zsh** on Mac:

1. Run `vim ~/.zshrc`
2. Press `i`
3. Paste `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"`
4. Press `esc`
5. Type `:wq!` and press `enter`
6. Restart the terminal

If successfull `which flutterfire` will work.

Comment: Worked when I tried it with mason

Comment: worked for mac m1 pro

Comment: worked on mac air m1, amazing

Comment: worked on mac m2 pro

Comment: Thanks man! worked on Macbook M2 Pro.

Comment: No need to restart, you can just 
`source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 46):

Here is what worked for me:
`dart pub global run flutterfire_cli:flutterfire configure`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72640644/20406073

Comment: yes, this worked for me, but with project flag like:
dart pub global run flutterfire_cli:flutterfire configure --project=YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID

Comment: worked for me already few times, thank you a lot

Answer (score 15):

[I am using Mac]
This helped me, Just keep in mind when you follow below steps from official [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android):-

```
 npm install -g firebase-tools
 firebase login
 dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
 flutterfire configure
```

If `flutterfire configure` doesnot work then, Add:

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

to your `.bash_profile` from Home directory of your mac.
Now, Restart your system, And after opening your system, try `flutterfire configure` again in VS Code. It will work. Then:

```
flutter pub add firebase_core
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 2):

[[image: 1]

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/saurav/Downloads/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

1. Run vim ~/.zshrc
2. Press i
3. Paste flutter/bin path as shown in the image
4. Paste export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
5. Press esc
6. Type :wq! and press enter
7. Restart the terminal

Comment: This is just a copy of the existing answer

Answer (score 1):

set path to flutterfire by running command
vim ~/.bash_profile
press i for insert
paste the path
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
press esc key to save then :wq to exit

you can run
which flutterfire to check path

Answer (score 1):

my case

```
 npm install -g firebase-tools
 firebase login
 dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

add path in .zhrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/saurav/Downloads/flutter/bin"
```

Run again

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

Restart your Macbook

```
flutterfire configure
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Follow These Screenshot One By One
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]